# Отображение символов вопроса

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Некорректно отображается сокращение русского текста, а именно, после сокращения появляется символ "вопроса".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приложите исходный код в котором происходит сокращение текста.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Текст обрезается по длине не учитывая многобайную кодировку. Скорее всего ваши строки хранятся в UTF-8, а обрезка выполняется по длине в байтах. В результате последний символ теряет один-два байта и вместо него отображается символ-заместитель.

Следует переписать функцию обрезки так, чтобы она учитывала многобайтовые символы, например используя функции `mb_substr()` или `iconv_substr()`

См. также:

1. http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-substr.php
2. http://php.net/manual/ru/function.iconv-substr.php

Comment: и что мне с этим сделать

Comment: 1. Переформулировать вопрос (вы можете его отредактировать) - привести примеры в текстовом виде и убрать картинку;